# Separating the Lanes with Contours

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am using Contours in Open-CV in C++ and I want to detect the lanes with that.
Basically I am using contours the detect the lanes and shapes and by putting filters before that I figure the actual Lines that I want.
Now I want to group them together so I know that these lines together make a lanes and the other ones make the other lane and so on.

I have tried with the distance between the contours to figure this out but it doesn't work completely, there are so many cases that the distances doesn't give the right thing.

So I was wondering if anybody knows how to this to be more efficient.

[image]

So I want to get out that {0,1,3,4,5,7} are together making a lane.
same for {2,6} and {8}.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share with us this **binary image** without the annoying numbers for testing purposes?

Comment: One idea would be to 1. [Detect features](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html) 2. For each feature, scan the neighbouring pixels and discover which way is the line pointing 3. Devise some criteria, based on distance and direction, to group the vectors for all features into continious lines.